# Copying data from AWS S3 Parquet file - limiting to just a few rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake user - searching for any advice available...)*

While copying data from AWS S3 Parquet file, I'm looking to select just a few rows based on a where condition to copy to Snowflake.  I've reviewed the following link (understanding that the copy transformation should allow me to add a filter clause while selecting data from stage file):

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/script-data-load-transform-parquet.html

However, from the example I see, it helps select a few columns not a few rows. I am looking to filter the rows based on a condition to load.

---

It has previously been recommended that the filter can be applied in the same way by applying the “Where” clause, but it doesn't seem to be a suitable solution for the user.

*Any recommendations?*

Answer (score 1):

Copy statement only supports simple select statements without where clause. Only option to filter the rows during load is to use limit and offset values.

```
create or replace file format sf_tut_parquet_format type = 'parquet';
create or replace stage sf_tut_stage1 file_format = sf_tut_parquet_format;
create or replace table prqnull1(data variant);
copy into prqnull1 (data) from (select * from @sf_tut_stage1 limit 3 offset 2);
```

The table contains parquet data constructed using below data.

```
cutoff_date,name
20081123, Ann
20080913, Beck
20100315, Carren
20110817, Dave
20161219, Emily
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that isn't possible.  You can limit which columns get loaded, but not which records get loaded.  I don't see anything in the documentation link provided that suggests that you can use a WHERE clause.  And the COPY INTO documentation also does not offer that ability.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-parquet